# ArcGis JavaScript SDK how to extent mapView to show all feature layers?

Tags: arcgis

I have 3 different feature layers and when I apply some filtering, like selecting a location (changing the queryExpression) I need the mapView to extent to match all new features from all feature layers. Any easy way to do this? I can't find anything to help me with this.